# VowPal Wabbit for Ubuntu 18, Java 1.8

Tags: java, ubuntu-18.04, vowpalwabbit

We've been using VowPal Wabbit on Ubuntu 16.  We want to move to Ubuntu 18 but there doesn't appear to be a VW build for Ubuntu 18.  First - does one exists? Secondly, if not, can someone point me to the instructions to build and make a Ubuntu 18 compatible library?  We use Java and JNI to talk to the library currently.

Thanks,
Ron

Answer (score 0):

We haven't got proper binary releases at the moment, so you'll need to build from source. Docs are somewhat sparse on this, so I'll go over it here.

To build the Java JNI lib on Ubuntu you need the dependencies:

```sh
sudo apt install libboost-dev libboost-thread-dev libboost-program-options-dev libboost-system-dev libboost-math-dev libboost-test-dev zlib1g-dev cmake g++ default-jdk
```

From here: https://github.com/VowpalWabbit/vowpal_wabbit/wiki/Dependencies#ubuntu

Then you need to use CMake to generate the build files and run the build:

```sh
# The important bit here is that the submodules are downloaded.
git clone --recursive https://github.com/VowpalWabbit/vowpal_wabbit.git
cd vowpal_wabbit
mkdir build
cd build
cmake .. -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DWARNINGS=Off -DBUILD_JAVA=On -DBUILD_DOCS=Off -DBUILD_PYTHON=Off -DSTATIC_LINK_VW_JAVA=On -DBUILD_TESTS=Off
make vw_jni -j `nproc`
cd ..
mvn test -f java/pom.xml
```

- `-DBUILD_JAVA=On` Java is optional so this is needed to have the target generated
- `-DSTATIC_LINK_VW_JAVA=On` This will statically link some dependencies, optional
- The `vw_jni` target also runs `mvn check`
- `-DBUILD_DOCS=Off -DBUILD_PYTHON=Off -DBUILD_TESTS=Off` Saves time by not doing things you don't need

Java is built and tested as part of CI, an example script can be seen here.
An example of this which runs in CI is here:

- https://github.com/VowpalWabbit/vowpal_wabbit/blob/master/.pipelines/build-linux-java.yml
- https://github.com/VowpalWabbit/vowpal_wabbit/blob/master/.scripts/linux/build-static-java.sh

Comment: Does any of the above change with 8.2.0?  I followed the build instructions on github and all is well.  Not sure about the JNI lib though.

Comment: The above instructions do not work for 8.2.0.  Are there specific directions for that version?  Also - just curious - is there anything from 8.2.0 to the latest release that is API breaking?  That is, could I upgrade to the latest from 8.2.0 without much grief?

Comment: 8.2.0 was before the CMake build system, so quite different. Not sure about 8.2.0, that was quite some time ago. Your best bet is to look at the readme at that point in history for build instructions. I'm not too familiar with changes before 8.6, so I can't comment on API stability there. But you're probably pretty okay if using the command line interface. Since 8.6 there is a focus to be more intentional on API changes.

Comment: Just to verify - If i'm building 8.8.1 and using ubuntu 18, I believe I will need to change the Java code so it can pull in the correct library at runtime.  Is that correct?  And I should name the library appropriately, right?  Just want to make sure I've got my arms around the scope of things.  I'm going to try to move the team off of 8.2.

Comment: I just realized that we have the Java bindings released here: https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.github.vowpalwabbit/vw-jni It should pull in the right runtime lib.

Comment: I was able to get things to build from source and things are good.  It's good to have a pre-built option, so thank you.  I do have a question regarding our models that are being built and ingested in 8.2.  What kinds of problems do you think I'll run into when using 8.8.1.3?  I couldn't find any docs from release to release that could tell me the list of changes.  I did have a slight code hit since VWFloatLearner is now abstract, but didn't seem like a big deal.

Comment: Migrating a model from 8.2 to 8.8.1 is a decent jump but I'm not aware of any specific issues. I think the best bet is to use `--readable_model` for a 8.2 VW and 8.8.1 VW and visually inspect the model to see if they both seem to be equivalent.